# Retorna valor de um array dinâmicamente

Tags: php, array, loop, return

Tenho um array

```
$teste = [1,2,3,4];

<Input type="text" value ="teste[0]" />

//retorna "1"
```

Como eu poderia trazer todos os valores do array nos inputs?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que você precisa e o que você já tentou. Não está claro qual é exatamente sua dúvida.

Comment: @fernandosavio as coisas começam a fazer mais sentido quando a pergunta ta bem formatada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um loop no seu array adicionando um `input` para cada item:

```
<?php
  $teste = [1,2,3,4];

  foreach ($teste as $t) {
    echo "<input type='text' value='$t'>";
  }
?>
```

[resultado no ideone](https://ideone.com/XQfWyu)